# How to configure additional listener in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle

I am trying to configure a listener in Oracle 12c database and running into issues. We have a listener that is configured for port 1521 which works fine. I am trying to configure another listener on port 8011 and seeing the errors while starting it.

Here is my listener.ora file:

```
ADMIN_RESTRICTIONS_LISTEN_PDM = ON
INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_LISTEN_PDM = 5

LISTEN_PDM =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST=
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1 )(PORT = 1521 ))
      )
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.11.73)(PORT = 8011))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC8011))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTEN_PDM =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (ORACLE_HOME = /ora01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1)
      (SID_NAME = PDM)
    )
  )
```

Here is my tnsnames.ora file:

```
ip-192-168-11-73.csn.com =
  (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 8011))
   ) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = PDM)) )
```

When I run the lsnrctl start/stat command on the listener configured on port 8011, I see the below error:

```
[oracle@ip-192-168-11-73 ~]$ lsnrctl stat LISTENER

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 17-APR-2017 17:50:38

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.11.73)(PORT=8011)))
TNS-12547: TNS:lost contact
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00517: Lost contact
   Linux Error: 104: Connection reset by peer
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC8011)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                17-APR-2017 17:50:02
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 36 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /ora01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /ora01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/ip-192-168-11-73/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.11.73)(PORT=8011)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC8011)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

I followed the instructions provided here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/rtsai/entry/how_to_configure_multiple_oracle

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 8011 was not open. I could resolve this by opening the port.

Thanks.